# Cross Platform Android Library Paths in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, github, android-library, path-separator

Here's the issue: We have a team of 4 people working on a few Android libraries and apps dependent on those libraries. Some of us are on Windows 7, others are on OS X, and we use GitHub. Several times a day, we each have to change the Android Library paths because the project.properties files stores platform dependent paths (that is, it uses \ as a Windows path separator and / as an OS X path separator.) It's really annoying and we waste a good deal of time on it.

Does anyone have a decent solution for this? It seems to me that surely there must exist something like the CPP where we can throw an ifdef into project.properties and have it automatically fix paths to match our OS whenever we pull from github or something.

Oh, and to be clear, we're frequently adding and removing libraries, or changing which libraries depend on each other, and all of us modify all of the libraries on a regular basis... so simply adding project.properties to gitignore wouldn't work very well, because we'd still have to regularly modify the libraries to make sure we have all the correct things included.

Comment: Have you considered writing a script to do it?  I'm not sure if git has the ability to run a script on checkin/checkout, but if it does it should be a simple replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last project that I worked with, we would modify the paths for our system and add the file to our .gitignore. It was a mature product so the paths rarely changed.

Comment: Our paths changes multiple times a week - we're working on a large collection of libraries and constantly shifting different components between the libraries. It's probable that part of our issue is we didn't plan enough in advance, but we didn't really know what we getting into when we started... I don't think we could have planned any better than we did.

Comment: Yes, you'd have thought that given how many platforms Eclipse runs on THEY would have thought this out better. Given that it was from IBM and I worked for IBM, it doesn't surprise me in the least. Now that I'm done snarking at my former employer ;), I'd suggest following Gabe's suggestion. Install Perl or Cygwin on the Windows machines and use Git's post-merge hook to rewrite the paths in the project file. Either by a local config file or by discovering the workspace directory path.

Comment: I ultimately wrote a small C program that handled this and was hooked in. I've since moved on to another job and lost that program and its source... I doubt the company I had been working for exists anymore. Marking your answer as correct.